# Vim: Move end of word to start globally

Tags: regex, vim

After reading about [Vim `regex`s](http://vimregex.com/#substitute), my head hurts.

I'd like to change all words *ending in* `_bar` into words *starting with* `bar_`.

So for example:

```
var variable_foo = "foo",
    more_foo = "foo";
```

would become:

```
var foo_variable = "foo",
    foo_more = "foo"; // New variable names
```

I know the answer will involve `:%s/<something>/<something else>/g`.

The answer should be robust to coding-style word boundaries like this:

```
(inside_parens_foo)
```

changes to

```
(foo_inside_parens)
```

Comment: Use `:%s/\(\w\+\)_\(\w\+\)/\2_\1/g` as suggested by [Peter Rincker](http://stackoverflow.com/users/438329/peter-rincker).

Answer (score 4):

As @devnull stated you need to use back-references:

```
:%s/\(\w\+\)_\(\w\+\)/\2_\1/g
```

Use `\w` to capture word like characters, `[0-9A-Za-z_]`. I would also recommend using the `c` flag to confirm changes.

As @benjifisher stated using the `\v` to turn on "very magic" will cut down the line noise:

```
:%s/\v(\w+)_(\w+)/\2_\1/g
```

For more help see:

```
:h :s_c
:h \1
:h /\w
:h /\+
:h /\v
```

Comment: This is a fantastic answer. Would you be able to add a little about what the `+` symbol does? (Or how to find help on it?) Then it will be complete!

Comment: The `+` is a regex quantifier. It means one or more times. I would suggest you look at `:h pattern` for vim regex information. I suggest you look for some regex tutorials or at the very least this [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2759417/438329).